# QTimer in multithreaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtimer

Okay, so I've completely lost in QTimer. The problem is: I have multithreaded application, and I need to do some work on QTimer's timeout. I've done like this:

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
timer->setSingleShot(true);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), someObject, SLOT(work()));
```

And this did not work. Sometimes, work() was not called at all, sometimes it was called when I closed program, and sometimes all seemed normal.
So I've come to idea that timer needs thread. To provide MCV example :

```
class Tester : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
 Tester(QObject* par = 0) : QObject(par)
 {
 }
 public slots:
 void greet()
 {
  qDebug()<<"hello";
 }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

 QTimer* timer1 = new QTimer();

 QThread* thread = new QThread();
 Tester* tester = new Tester();

 timer1->setInterval(500);
 timer1->setSingleShot(false);
 timer1->moveToThread(thread);


 QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), timer1, SLOT(start()));

 QObject::connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeout()), tester, SLOT(greet()));

 QObject::connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeout()), timer1, SLOT(deleteLater()));
 QObject::connect(timer1, SIGNAL(destroyed()), thread, SLOT(quit()));

 thread->start();

 thread->wait();

 delete thread;
 delete tester;

 return a.exec();
}
```

And this example does nothing. It does not greet me, so timeout is not called, and it does not end, so thread is not stopped. So questions are:
1. What is wrong with this code?
2. How properly use QTimer in multithreaded environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just calling [QTimer::setInterval](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#interval-prop) doesn't start the QTimer. It just sets the interval in which the [QTimer::timeout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#timeout) signal is emitted. You didn't start the QTimer. Use [QTimer::start](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#start-2).

I think you're doing several mistakes here. You need to move the timer to thread after all the connections are made. Not sure how safe would be to start the timer when the thread starts because at that point, the timer would be in one thread and the thread object would be in another thread. `QTimer` must be started from the same thread in which it was created. The `QThread` object is just a thread handler and it lives in the thread in which was created. See the modifications I made to your example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>

//#include "tester.h"

class Tester : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Tester(QObject* par = 0) : QObject(par)
    {
    }

public slots:
    void greet()
    {
        qDebug()<<"hello";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTimer* timer1 = new QTimer();

    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    Tester* tester = new Tester();

    timer1->setInterval(500);
    timer1->setSingleShot(false);
    timer1->start();

    QObject::connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeout()), tester, SLOT(greet()));

    timer1->moveToThread(thread);

    thread->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

It's not the safest/best fix(memory leaks and other) but it is, i hope, an example on which you can build.

This would be in my opinion the right and without memory leaks way to use a `QTimer` in another `QThread`:

*handler.h*

```
#ifndef HANDLER_H
#define HANDLER_H

#include <QObject>

class QTimer;
class QThread;
class Tester;

class Handler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Handler(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Handler();

    void exec();

private:
    QTimer* timer;
    QThread* thread;
    Tester* tester;
};

#endif // HANDLER_H
```

*handler.cpp*

```
#include "handler.h"
#include "tester.h"

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QCoreApplication>

Handler::Handler(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    timer = new QTimer;
    thread = new QThread(this);
    tester = new Tester(this);

    timer->setInterval(500);
    timer->setSingleShot(false);

    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), tester, SLOT(greet()));
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(destroyed()), timer, SLOT(deleteLater()));
}

Handler::~Handler()
{
    thread->wait();
}

void Handler::exec()
{
    timer->start();

    timer->moveToThread(thread);

    thread->start();
}
```

*tester.h*

```
#ifndef TESTER_H
#define TESTER_H

#include <QObject>

class Tester : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Tester(QObject* par = 0);

public slots:
    void greet();
};


#endif // TESTER_H
```

*tester.cpp*

```
#include "tester.h"

#include <QDebug>

Tester::Tester(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Tester::greet()
{
    qDebug()<<"hello";
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "handler.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Handler handler;
    handler.exec();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please, read code carefully QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), timer1, SLOT(start())); Or am I wrong?

Comment: Okay, thank you, but what should I do to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: @DoctorMoisha I think that this is only a didactic example. In practice you would have all these objects as members in a class. This class would handle the lifetime of these objects and the memory should be freed in the class' destructor.

Comment: Or just use QObject hierarchy

Comment: @paulm Yes, parenting is also a solution.

Comment: It is not my case, I've tried to delete object on timer, and every solution either does not delete something, either introduces runtime errors. I'll try to ask other, more particular question.

Comment: If there would not be other answers to both my questions and without memory leaks - I'll mark it

Comment: @DoctorMoisha See my edits. I hope this concludes the answer.

Comment: It is a big pity, but no. My problem is a bit more complicated, and I think I need ask another question. But it is good answer to this question so - tick. Thank you.